# Showing a set is of $\sigma$-finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> If $f$ is integralable over the measure space $\left(X,\mathcal{M},\mu\right)$ then the set
> $\{x:f(x)\neq0\}$ is of $\sigma$-finite measure.

*My attempt:*

Let $E:=\{x:f(x)\neq0\}$. Notice,

$$E = \underbrace{\{x:f(x)>0\}}_{A}\cup\underbrace{\{x:f(x)<0\}}_{B}.$$

Notice also,

$$A = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \quad\text{ and }\quad B = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n,$$

where $A_n:=\{x:f(x)>\frac{1}{n}\}$ and $B_n:=\{x:f(x)<-\frac{1}{n}\}$.

Then,

$$E = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n,$$

where $E_n = A_n\cup B_n$.

Since $f$ is integralable over the measure space $\left(X,\mathcal{M},\mu\right)$,

$$\infty>\int_{A_n}|f|>\int_{A_n}\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\mu(A_n)$$

$$\infty>\int_{B_n}|f|>\int_{B_n}\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\mu(B_n).$$

This implies that $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ and $\mu(B_n)<\infty$. As $\mu(E_n) = \mu(A_n) + \mu(B_n)$, we have that $\mu(E_n)<\infty.$

Thus, $E$ the countable union of measurable sets with finite measure.

Comment: Looks okay to me. More concise and in the same line you can go for $\{f\neq0\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{|f|>\frac1n\}$

Comment: @drhab: Thanks for the conformation! True, that is a bit more concise.